# Home internet setup

Tags: networking, router, internet

I need to setup my internet connection in the best way possible for my house.

Until now, I’ve used a single modem/router for one side of the house and I have a range extender to cover the other side. My computer is positioned in a room covered by the range extender and I have constant ping spikes I couldn’t explain. I’ve optimized my computer settings and also the main modem settings, but I couldn’t get rid of the lag spikes. So I’ve come to the conclusion that I’m losing packets through the Wi-Fi connection.

I need a setup that gets rid of the Wi-Fi side of things, and gets everything through cables.
Is there a way I could accomplish this without having long cables across the house and without losing speed? (I can’t move the main modem from that spot…)

I have 32 mbps in down and 15 in up, also I would like a solution without the need to open up the walls of my house to get cables through them.

I’m really sorry for the length of the post and for the bad english, bur I couldn’t find a shorter way to describe the situation… also it may be impossible to get a solution with all the limitations I gave, so feel free to comment with any other solution if you think it’s impossible to accomplish what I’ve asked!

Comment: So you want cables ("gets rid of the Wi-Fi") but without cables?... The only thing to try would be Powerline Adapters/Ethernet Over Power, but they are also not necessarily the most reliable.

Comment: Without cables the best you can do is get better modem and extender. Or PowerLine as mentioned above. But you will be spending money for solutions with no guarantee of success.

Comment: Just one cable could transform your extender into an Access Point; or you could run a switch from there if that's where most of the devices are. 32mbps is pretty slow these days, so even just a half decent access point would be faster than your ISP line. [Extenders suffer not only bufferbloat but also have to share the bandwidth with the other point]

Comment: Power Line adapters, or figure routes through closets (to hide the conduit).  I do this to get top quality internet to my second floor.  From there, Ubiquiti Access Points upstairs.  Works great.

Comment: Powerline depends on your mains connectivity. It doesn't like to cross rings. People usually find out after they've bought the kit that it won't work in their house. [My ISP sent me some for free. I tried it right round the house.. with spotty results based on each ring main & how it interconnected with others. Basically it would work on each floor but not 'climb any stairs'. As my house is split-level over 5 floors that made it less than useful ;)

Comment: Running a single cable would get you at least gigabit or 10 gigabit, and your internet speed is no where near that.  You could use a switch on the other end to get you more ports.  Although you don't want to open your walls, its the best option.  Maybe you can come down from the attic(as attic are mostly unfinished), or across the basement ceiling.  If you can drill through the wall joist in the middle, shove the cable to the bottom, and make a small hole to fish the cable out.

Comment: Alright, thank you for all the replies. I’ve understood that the most reliable way to set this up is to get at least one cable…

I’m paying for a 100 mbps, but only receiving 32… maybe I should change ISP -.-

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware of two solutions that fit your bill:

- [Powerline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication) Adapters: Transmits the network signal through your home's electrical circuits
- [MoCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_over_Coax_Alliance) Adapters: Lets you run ethernet over coax cables

MoCA is definitely the better option if you have coax, which most houses do. You basically put a MoCA adapter on both ends, then it's plug and play with ethernet cables. There are adapters that even go up to 2.5 Gbps. I believe they even let you keep using the coax for television at the same time.

That being said, if your main issue has been bad WiFi, you might consider setting up a [mesh WiFi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_mesh_network) network. Basically you have multiple "extenders" or access points, but they all act as one SSID, so your devices will automatically switch to the closest one instead of you having to manually switch networks.

A mesh network can be all wireless or wired (called wired or wireless "backhaul"). I would definitely do wired if possible, meaning all the WiFi access points are wired back to the router, instead of the signal being relayed wirelessly, which can cause signal loss for each jump. You could still use MoCA to get wired ethernet to different parts of your house, while also putting mesh access points there so you get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll gather some more information about the MoCA setup!

Comment: I use powerline - its 'nice' to be able to use existing cables, but assume that you'll only get 1/2 to 1/3 the rated speed. Get the passthrough ones, and plug them straight into a wall (they do filtering of noise) and *ideally* plug any switch mode power devices through a multisocket. Also I used to lose connection whenever our old, dodgy dryer would run. Can't beat the "simplicity" of them but they're a wee bit fiddly